# Android Firestore: order posts by document value

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following database configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN2zT.png)

collection Posts -> postID -> in here another collection called LikesNumber -> document currentLikesNumber -> field currentNoOfLikes

In my application I want to sort my posts according to certain features. I have already implemented the code to order by post category, it goes like this:

```
public void getHorror(){
    blog_list = new ArrayList<>();
    blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);
    blog_list_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    blog_list_view.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);
    blog_list_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        blog_list_view.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                Boolean reachedBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1); //if we reach bottom
                if(reachedBottom){

                    loadMore();
                }
            }
        });

        Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").whereEqualTo("category","Horror").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING); //show newest posts first
        firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        if (isFirstPageLoaded) {
                            lastVisible = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                            blog_list.clear();
                        }
                        for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                String blogPostId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                                BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class).withId(blogPostId);
                                if (isFirstPageLoaded) {
                                    blog_list.add(blogPost);
                                } else {
                                    blog_list.add(0, blogPost);
                                }
                                blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        isFirstPageLoaded = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    blog_list.clear();
    blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

basically, when the category field has the given string in it, my recycler adapter will be updated only showing those certain posts.

Now, I want to do the same thing, but I want to sort them by `currentNoOfLikes` from High to Low. My problem is that I do not know how to access the data within currentNoOfLikes. This is what I have tried

```
public void getLikesHL(){
    blog_list = new ArrayList<>();
    blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);
    blog_list_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    blog_list_view.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);
    blog_list_view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        blog_list_view.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                Boolean reachedBottom = !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1); //if we reach bottom
                if(reachedBottom){

                    loadMore();
                }
            }
        });

        Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("LikesNumber").orderBy("currentNoOfLikes",Query.Direction.DESCENDING); //show newest posts first
        firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        if (isFirstPageLoaded) {
                            lastVisible = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                            blog_list.clear();
                        }
                        for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                String blogPostId = doc.getDocument().getId();
                                BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class).withId(blogPostId);
                                if (isFirstPageLoaded) {
                                    blog_list.add(blogPost);
                                } else {
                                    blog_list.add(0, blogPost);
                                }
                                blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        isFirstPageLoaded = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    blog_list.clear();
    blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But when the recycler adapter is updated, it is empty. For some reason I cannot get the data from currentNoOfLikes and update it from highest number values to lowest ones (DESCENDING order).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("LikesNumber").orderBy("currentNoOfLikes",Query.Direction.DESCENDING); //show newest posts first
```

into this:

```
firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query firstQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").document(postID).collection("LikesNumber").orderBy("currentNoOfLikes",Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

The collection `LikesNumber` is a subcollection, therefore to access it you need to go through Posts -> postsID -> LikesNumber then you can get the data.